# Is there a way to read and save as single operation with Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have ASP.NET Core project, where one of the requirements is that every person can have many products, but only one with type "CAR". So while I am saving new offer with "CAR" type I am doing something like this:

```
var products = productsRepository.GetClientProducts();
if (!products.Any(x => x.Type == "CAR"))
{
    productsRepository.Add(productWithTypeNew);
}
```

But what if someone add new "CAR" offer between my check and save? I will add another and my Db will be broken..

Comment: You can use a DB constraint, or maybe a mutex.

Comment: Is this Dapper? This looks more like Entity Framework. Typically with Dapper you write your own SQL statements, rather than letting a c# library generate the SQL for you.

Comment: @gunr2171 They're using a repository which presumably is using Dapper.

Comment: @gunr2171 there's a fair few frameworks which wrap around dapper "SimpleCRUD" for example. It does look like EF but it's still dapper.

Comment: Side note: if adding multiple rows breaks your database, then your database design could do with some work. Put a unique constraint on the table to prevent multiple entries.

Answer (score 1):

Well spotted, if unlikely. It's why database servers have the concept of constraints. So in SQL Server terms you would design your Products table so that the Type column has a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint. Then you handle the exception if that is violated when writing the record.

Comment: But how to create constraint that allow to add only 1 row with Type="CAR"

Comment: Well, you need to able to change your database schema. If you can then to add a unique constraint in TSQL it would be along the lines of :
ALTER TABLE Products ADD CONSTRAINT unique_type UNIQUE(Type)
Once you do this it becomes impossible at a database level to add a row with a duplicate value in the Type column. Note that you could add a row with a null value in Type, which is one way a unique constraint differs from a primary key constraint. But that's easy to trap at the client side.

Answer (score 0):

A few options come to mind for dealing with this requirement. The first (set up a constraint and catch the rare exception) has already been mentioned by Alan B in his answer above. We're all guessing a bit on your database schema, but I suspect you might need a [filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) to set up the constraint properly.

Another option, if your ORM framework supports it, would be to pass a transaction to each of the methods. "Raw" Dapper certainly supports this, but from the code above it looks like there is another layer of abstraction involved.

A final option, and probably the way I would go, is to wrap the logic (start transaction, check records, add record) in a stored procedure and then create a method in your repository to just call that directly. The ORM might just be getting in the way in your case.